# Changing Sql Server session state provider to use custom schema instead of dbo

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I need to configure my ASP.NET SQL Server session state provider to use a custom schema instead of the default `dbo`.

Is this achievable with just configuration change or do we need to write a custom session state provider? Any pointers will be of great help.

Technology stack : .NET 4.0 and Sql Server 2008

Comment: Yeah I think what you said is still true. I can see dbo inside the .net code and writing a custom provider might be an overkill for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into this once. The issue is that the DotNet code will call a stored procedure, and that stored procedure (in the DotNet code) will be calling something like dbo.DoSomething. Thus you're stuck.

Take my info with a grain of salt, it was 2.0/3.0 days when I look at this. 
But I doubt that changed in 4.0/4.5.

But it stinks, because I (like you if I'm inferring correctly)....like to use alternate schema names as a "namespace" for organizing, so not everything under the Sun is a dbo.Something.

But yeah, I would love to see an addition  parameter like below

```
<sessionState 
            mode="SQLServer"
            sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;user id=<username>;password=<strongpassword>"
            cookieless="false" 
            timeout="20" 
            DbSchemaName="MySchemaName"
    />
```

For future googlers out there, DbSchemaName="MySchemaName" is something I just completely made up.